# How to read all the data cells and only highlight the cells which have a more than 10 characters

Tags: excel, vba

I need to read all the data cell which have the entries but I only need to highlight the cells which have a character more than 10 in that data cell.

For example:

In the A column I need to read all the data but my condition is that I need to highlight the cell which contains more than 10 char.

Likewise In the B column I need to do the same thing but here I need to highlight the cell which contains more than 12 char.

Likewise I want to implement one solution for all the columns which contains the data.

Please help me to resolve it.

The code I tried:

```
Sub Dendrinos2()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lr To 2 Step -1
        If Range("C" & i).Value > 6 Then Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        If Range("G" & i).Value > 3 Then Range("G" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        If Range("I" & i).Value > 3 Then Range("I" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        If Range("C" & i).Value < -3 Then Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        If Range("G" & i).Value < -3 Then Range("G" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        If Range("I" & i).Value < -3 Then Range("I" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        If Range("E" & i).Value = "--" Then Range("E" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex
        If Range("G" & i).Value = "--" Then Range("G" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex
        If Range("I" & i).Value = "--" Then Range("I" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex  
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to do that with code? Then post what code you have written so far. If you don't want to use code, this can be done with conditional formatting, but that kind of question belongs on Superuser.com, not here. Please take the [tour] and then edit your question to make it better before it gets closed.

Comment: You can do this with conditional formatting. `Len(Range)>10` for `Column A` and `Len(Range)>12`for `Column B`. Then, just apply the rule to your relevant ranges. I would shy away from applying this rule down an entire column though.

Comment: No i need a code to do this i already have done this via conditional forwarding.

Comment: So what *exactly* is stopping you from doing this?  If you don't know any VBA at all, this is not the place for your question: if you do know some VBA then *make a start* and then post your code when you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Tim. I hope now you got my expectations can you please share your code for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional formatting with a simple formula that covers columns A and B.

```
Sub highlightLength()
    With Worksheets("sheet3")
        With .Range("A:B")
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=len(a1)>(column(a1)+4)*2"
            With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                .Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your code it does working but in my B Column i have some Strings mingled with Numbers and spl characters those things are not highlighting  Char+Numeric (i.e RAT1232342312) (RAT/expsa/moreetc)

Comment: Please paste this data (DATA0069642 , DATA0069964) on A or B and please replicate the same thing from your end and confirm me whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
Sub Dendrinos2()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    lr = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lr To 2 Step -1
        Checklength sht.Range("A" & i), 10
        Checklength sht.Range("B" & i), 12
        CheckLimits sht.Range("C" & i), -3, 6
        CheckLimits sht.Range("G" & i), -3, 3
        CheckLimits sht.Range("I" & i), -3, 3
        CheckDashes sht.Range("E" & i), sht.Range("A" & i)
        CheckDashes sht.Range("G" & i), sht.Range("A" & i)
        CheckDashes sht.Range("I" & i), sht.Range("A" & i)
    Next i

End Sub

Sub CheckLimits(c As Range, ll, ul)
    With c
        If .Value < ll Or .Value > ul Then .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End With
End Sub

Sub CheckDashes(c As Range, cA As Range)
    With c
        If .Value = "--" Then
            .Interior.ColorIndex = cA.Interior.ColorIndex
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub Checklength(c As Range, l As Long)
    With c
        If Len(.Value) > l Then .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim If I need to check the length of the string on individual colunm how I can do it ?

Comment: For an example I should have 12 character on all the A column and 10 character on the b column and 7 on c and so on. Can you please edit your code to meet this requirement. Thanks in advance.